# IndentationError while converting PHP function to Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried writing this code:

```
def stopWords(text, stopwords):
  stopwords = map(to_lower(x),stopwords)
  pattern = '/[0-9\W]/'
  text = re.sub(pattern, ',', text)
  text_array = text.partition(',');
  text_array = map(to_lower(x), text_array);
  keywords = []
for term in text_array:
  if(term in stopwords):
     keywords.append(term)
 return filter(None, keywords)
  
stopwords = open('stop_words.txt','r').read()
text = "All words in the English language can be classified as one of the eight different parts of speech."
print(stopWords(text, stopwords))
```

But I get an error that says `IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: You did not properly intent your code lines. Unlike in PHP indentation is very important in Python.

Comment: Do you know why you need indentation in Python? Are you aware that your line `for term in text_array:` ends the function?

Comment: @Matthias no, i am not properly aware about that, but i am interested to know about that

Comment: @Matthias ok got it, no. of spaces (enter) matter in python

Comment: Indentation is the way to define things that belong together. In PHP you use `{` and `}` and the indentation of the code is optional. In Python the indentation of the code defines the code structure.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` should be indented, as you write it, it seems to be out of the function. Moreover, the last return is not aligned both with the for or the function.

A correct indentation should look like this:

```
def stopWords(text, stopwords):
  stopwords = map(to_lower(x),stopwords)
  pattern = '/[0-9\W]/'
  text = re.sub(pattern, ',', text)
  text_array = text.partition(',');
  text_array = map(to_lower(x), text_array);
  keywords = []
  for term in text_array:
    if(term in stopwords):
      keywords.append(term)
  return filter(None, keywords)
```

Comment: @LovepreetSinghBatth as long as you correctly indent the function, it should work